# Spring boot - SSL config embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, ssl, embedded-tomcat-8

My Spring Boot service runs on server.name.com:8088 and I have purchased a certificate for server.name.com . I already installed the certificate on the server, the thing is, I don't know if I can use this certificate for my Spring Boot application. The CA has provided me with 3 .pem files - a root, intermediate and certificate for server.name.com . i am running Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat, so I'm wondering how to configure SSL for it.

Comment: You already asked the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776439/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-ssl-config) earlier. Which got closed with links to other topics which answer this, asking the same again will yield the same result.

Comment: Just to be clear. My first question was marked incorrectly as duplicate. Please note, that I'm not asking how to use .pem files for SSL config of spring boot. This has already been aswered. I'm asking, if I can use the same certificate to configure the SSL for embedded tomcat.